# regular expression to filter out dates from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['','2022-03-31', 'euss', 'projects','2021-03-31']
```

I want to write a regular expression such that I delete all other items from the list and only keep those that have a date format. For example, 2022-03-31 and 2021-03-31.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to make a difference when I print my list out:

```
my_list = [re.sub(r"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)",r"\3-\1-\2",i) for i in list(my_list) ]
```

Comment: You're using `/` where you should have `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if there regex matches the string:

```py
result = []
rx = re.compile(r'(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)')
for i in my_list:
    if rx.search(i):                          # Check if the regex matches the string
        result.append(rx.sub(r"\3-\1-\2", i)) # Add modified string to resulting list
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NDkfou).
Output:

```
['31-2022-03', '31-2021-03']
```

You may write it as:

```py
rx = re.compile(r'(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)')
my_list = [rx.sub(r"\3-\1-\2", i) for i in my_list if rx.search(i)]
```

Comment: could we also change it to a one line thing? Like in the regex example in the qs

Comment: @x89 I added the list comprehension syntax.